# Post thumbnail image not showing when share on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I am trying to develop this blog http://www.racecarwow.com . I have used youtube video thumbnail for post thumbnail .  In single post , there is a facebook share button. When i click on it, it is not showing the post thumbnail image.  it only show a fix image for all post thumbnail during share. I have used the following code for post thumbnil

```
 <a class="thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <img class="img-responsive"  src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $youtube_code; ?>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="<?php the_title()?>" />
 </a>
```

Here `$youtube_code` is coming from custom field. I have also try this following way

```
 <a class="thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php if($post_img_src){?>
        <img src="<?php echo $post_img_src[0] ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>" class="img-responsive">

    <?php } else{?>

    <img class="img-responsive"  src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $youtube_code; ?>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="<?php the_title()?>" />
   <?php }?>
    </a>
```

And i have used the following code for share post

```
 <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&t=<?php echo urlencode($post->post_title); ?>"target="_blank">

  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Share on facebook
 </a>
```

Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your thumbnail image in a meta tag that Facebook can read for each post:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $youtube_code; ?>/hqdefault.jpg" />
```

I think you have a plugin that has the Facebook meta tags, you might need to edit the plugin in order for your custom thumbnails to show with the other meta info.

You can debug your website on Facebook here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug